# How to use scipy-leastsq fit complex function?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, complex-numbers, least-squares

I want to fit my data by complex function,such as `(aj)^b/(1+(aj)^(2b)`.But leastsq can't do that.So I try to find a way to solve that:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import leastsq
import pylab as pl
import xlrd

def func(w,p):
    a,s,u=p
    d=complex(0,1) 
    f=u+(s-u)/(1+(d*w)**a)

    return f.imag 

def residuals(p, y, x):



    return y - func(x, p)
p0 = [0.5,20,10]
data=xlrd.open_workbook(r'C:\Users\limin\Desktop\mydata.xlsx')

table=data.sheets()[0]
xdata=table.col_values(0)
ydata_1=table.col_values(1) 

plsq = leastsq(residuals, p0, args=(ydata_1, xdata))

print(plsq[0])
```

When I run it,I got `can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'complex'`
I don't know why.
Really need your help!

Comment: Could you please try to build an example that uses simple ASCII file, I tried to reproduce your problem but `mydata.xlsx` is not available